# Extracting column index as a list

Tags: r, indices

I have a data frame of 12 columns. Columns 1-3 are character data, columns 4-10 are
numerics.  I want to create a list of all numeric columns, so I get c(4:10) for use
in a loop.

Comment: Use `unclass(df1[4:10])`.  If you want the index, why not just use 4:10

Comment: Because I don't want to count columns, the hack below with which/sapply does the job.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to find the index of numeric columns automatically, loop over the data.frame with `sapply`, check whether it is numeric (`is.numeric`) and wrap with `which`

```
indx <- which(sapply(df1, is.numeric))
```